# Latest Google Chrome troubles: tabs reload automatically

Tags: google-chrome

Currently I have Google Chrome Version 49.0.2623.87 m.

Approximately everything is okay with me before 1 month. But currently I am having a trouble with my Chrome Browser.
I have Win 8.1 and Core i-3 Dell Laptop. Ram 4GB.
Every tabs get reloaded when I am another page/app/window. Any help may appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable Automatic tab discarding, that is the new Chrome feature.

Put url `chrome://flags/#automatic-tab-discarding` in the Chrome browser and change value from Default to Disabled, when you will need to Relaunch chrome.

Comment: Trouble is automatically resolved after google chrome updates!